# yui charts - using connectPoints

Tags: javascript, yui

I am new to yui and trying to create a chart which displays only points (no connection between the points). I am using chart of type line and removing the connection between the points by setting "connectPoints" attribute to false (as mentioned in the [API](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/charts/#seriesstyles)). But the points are still connected. My code is as follows:

```
var data = '[{"lowRange":1.1 "dateTime":1329264000000},
                {"lowRange":1.1, "dateTime":1331769600000}]';

    var myAxes = {
        resultsData:{
            keys:["lowRange"],
            position:"left",
            type:"numeric",
            styles:{
                majorTicks:{
                    display: "none"
                }
            }
        },
        dateRange:{
            keys:["dateTime"],
            position:"bottom",
            type:"time",
            styles:{
                majorTicks:{
                    display: "none"
                },
                label: {
                    rotation:-45,
                    margin:{top:5}
                }
            }
        }
    };

   var seriesCollection = [{
        type:"line",
        xAxis:"dateRange",
        yAxis:"resultsData",
        xKey:"dateTime",            
        yKey:"lowRange",
        xDisplayName:"Date",
        yDisplayName:"Low Range",
        style: {                
            connectPoints:false             
        }
    }]  

var myChart = new Y.Chart({   
                    dataProvider:data, 
                    axes:myAxes, 
                    seriesCollection:seriesCollection,             
                    render:"#container"                       
                });
```

Can anyone please provide example of creating a graph like this or explain how to use connectPoints attribute?

Answer (score 0):

set the weight of the line to 0

```
 styles: {
            line: {
                weight: 0
            }
        }
```

Working example:
    http://jsfiddle.net/ffPG7/